# Swift: Moving annotations on MapView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I have a set of coordinates. I'm able to place custom annotations on the map but I couldn't move that annotation from one coordinate to another.

Basically, I'm running a loop to read each coordinate and trying to move annotation to that new coordinate.

I searched for resources online and found [this project](https://github.com/srujansimha/Moving-MKAnnotationView) very similar to my requirement. But that was written in Objective-C. I started developing iOS apps with Swift, so I have no idea about ObjC.

Any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change `annotation.coordinate`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This is the answer. An `MKPointAnnotation` has a read-write property called `coordinate`. If you change it, the annotation will move.

Comment: Answering here typically means providing some context behind the answer, as opposed to a simple code dump. By your comment you are able to give some context. Editing the answer to include the context will improve the answer and the ability of others to use it. See the [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for more